# In which way can i make use of AF_UNIX defined in Winsock2 in Windows

Tags: windows, porting

I have tried AF_UNIX with Windows socket API as follows:

```
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Above call returned `INVALID_SOCKET`. Last error was:

> 10047 "An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used".

The results were same when i tried the same with other socket 'type' values available in Windows like `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_RAW`.

So my question is: Is there any way to make use of AF_UNIX defined in 'Winsock2', so that its functionality similar to that in UNIX can be achieved here in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation on MSDN for the socket function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The values currently supported are AF_INET or AF_INET6, which are the Internet address family formats for IPv4 and IPv6. Other options for address family (AF_NETBIOS for use with NetBIOS, for example) are supported if a Windows Sockets service provider for the address family is installed.

So, unless you have installed a third-party service provider, you cannot use `AF_UNIX`.